# axios PUT request to rails-API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, axios, rails-api

I'm trying to post a new score instance to my rails-API but whenever I submit it the app resets itself without updating the state - the console isn't returning an error but it's not rendering the json either - so many things could be wrong but does anyone have an idea of where I should start looking.

my ScoreForm.js

```
export default class ScoreForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      strokes: null,
      selectedCourse: null,
    };

  }

  selectCourse(){
    console.log(this.refs.courseSelector.value);
    this.setState( {selectedCourse: this.refs.courseSelector.value} );
  }

  enterStrokes(){
    console.log(this.refs.typeStrokes.value);
    this.setState({strokes: this.refs.typeStrokes.value});
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
    const score = { strokes:this.state.strokes, user_id: this.props.currentUser, course_id: this.state.selectCourse}
    axios.put(
      `http://localhost:3001/api/v1/scores`, {score: score})
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.props.updateScores(response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }

  render() {
    var courseOptions = (this.props.courseList.map((course) => {
      return <option key={course.id} value={course.id}>{course.name}</option> ;
    }));
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input ref='typeStrokes' onChange={(e) => {this.enterStrokes(); } } />
        <select ref='courseSelector' onChange={(e) => { this.selectCourse(); } }>{courseOptions}</select>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

my rails routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      get 'users/scores' => 'scores#index'
      get 'users/:id/scores' => 'users#scores'
      resources :users
      resources :scores
      resources :courses
    end
  end

end
```

my scores_controller.rb

```
module Api::V1
  class ScoresController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_course

    def index
      @scores = Score.order("created_at DESC")
      render json: @scores
    end

    def create
      differential = (params[:score][:strokes].to_i) - @course.rating

      @score = Score.create(score_params.merge(:differential => differential))
      render json: @score
    end

    private

    def set_course
      @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
    end

    def score_params
      params.require(:score).permit(:user_id, :course_id, :strokes)
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: You don't have an `update` action implemented in your controller. So nothing happens on a PUT request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `rails routes` or `rake routes` (depending on your rails version) you will see what routes those resources defined in your `routes.rb` are creating. PUT requests get mapped into the `update` method in your controller, so you need to define it to update your resources and return the JSON response you're expecting in your React app.

Comment: No problem :) Mark my answer as accepted if you think you were able to solve your problem